# Nodejs: Do additional stuff after res.send

Tags: node.js, responsiveness

I'm using Node as webserver and I want to log every request to it into a database. I also want the user to receive the response as quickly as possible, so I came up with this code:

```
// ... putting together the response_data
res.send(response_data);
// ... now log the request into the DB and maybe do additional stuff
```

It works and I like the idea of putting some of the (time) expensive stuff behind the send. But as I'm new to Node I'm asking if this is a common pattern?

On Stackoverflow I just find people having problems bc they try to send additional data after res.send - but I never heard anybody saying "yeah this is a great feature for your responsiveness" so I'm not sure if there's a major flaw with this solution I just don't see yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't need to send anything back to the user as a result of the "additional" stuff then your approach is fine.

The problem most people come across is trying to send data down the response *after* the response has already been sent e.g.

```
res.send(response_data);
// do additional stuff
res.send(additional_data); // KABOOM!
```